# Когда оправдано употребление слова «варьироваться»?

Tags: выбор-слов

Уже давно задаюсь вопросом: можно ли и если можно, то когда уместно употреблять глагол «варьироваться»? Чисто интуитивно он почему-то режет слух и глаз, так и хочется поправить: «варьирует, а не варьируется!».
В очередной раз необходимо употребить это слово. Я бы сказал так: «Настройки варьируют в зависимости от операционной системы». Но чтобы проверить, пошёл на Грамоту.ру (наше всё), а там в орфографическом словаре даётся и «варьироваться» (в смысле «изменяться в зависимости от») тоже.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как же правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варьирует=имеет варианты=может изменяться, то есть слово "варьирует" уже носит возвратный смысл и без частицы СЯ. Поэтому все вариации на тему "варьируется" - безграмотность. Сравните: внутрь и вовнутрь, варьирует и варьируется. Что касается того, что кто-то что-то сознательно "варьирует" - это не возможно. Лучше: изменяет что-л, манипулирует чем-л. 
Рs: варьирует - не просто "изменяется", а может изменяться в каких-то пределах. А размер комиссии изменяют, а не варьируют. Например: курс доллара постоянно варьирует - полная бессмыслица. Курс доллара варьирует в пределах, определенных Центробанком; Курс доллара постоянно меняется - правильно.

Comment: Вот это очень похоже на то, что я интуитивно чувствовал, но никак не мог сформулировать. Спасибо! А есть источники всё же? Если кому-то показать/доказать надо будет, что «варьироваться» — это неграмотно?

Comment: Источники: учебники по биологии и статистике; или наберите в поисковике "варьирование признака".

Answer (score 4):

Своими действиями можно что-то "варьировать", а наблюдаемое пассивно (например, сопоставляемые прогнозы разных аналитиков на курс доллара или просто нечто, сознательно "варьируемое" другими) может "варьироваться" (видоизменяться в зависимости от условий наблюдения, иметь количественный разброс в каких-то пределах и т.п.). Эти слова примерно так же соотносятся, как "изменять" и "изменяться".

> Владельцы обменных пунктов **варьируют** размер комиссии при обмене валюты
>   в зависимости от места расположения пункта. Соответственно, с точки
>   зрения потенциальных посетителей, величина комиссии **варьируется** в
>   зависимости от района города.

Comment: То есть употребление «варьирует» в смысле «изменяется в зависимости от» вообще неверно? Но я очень часто слышал (и видел в серьёзных трудах) именно такое употребление... или они равноценны?

Comment: Думаю, что неверно, поскольку в русском этот глагол используется как переходный, в отличие напр. от "мигрирует" или от английского varies. В этом контексте нужно "варьируется".

Answer (score 1):

Окраска тела варьирует (=меняется) от светло- до черно-коричневой.

Глагол может быть переходным и непереходным.

ВАРЬИРОВАТЬ, Книжн. 1. что. Видоизменять, разнообразить, создавать новые варианты. В. тему, цвет, интонацию. 2. =Варьироваться. Форма и окраска хризантем варьирует.

Comment: И снова непонятно( Получается, что они синонимичны в этом контексте?

Comment: Да, получается, что варьировать и варьироваться - синонимы. Сравнить: Окраску можно менять/окраска меняется - окраску можно варьировать/окраска варьируется/окраска варьирует.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласна с автором строк: "Варьирует=имеет варианты=может изменяться, то есть слово "варьирует" уже носит возвратный смысл и без частицы СЯ. Поэтому все вариации на тему "варьируется" - безграмотность."
Слово "варьируетс" - также режет слух и также неоправдано и бессмысленно, как если сказать: "пары в зале вальсируются" или "водитель в машине рулится" - полная дикость!

Comment: «Полная дикость» — какой член предложения?